# SugarCRM: how to use preDisplay function in ViewQuickcreate?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to customize the quick create view to add a default value of a field in Sugar Community Edition 6.5.24

Similar code works fine for ViewEdit, but it seems never called in subpanels.

Current file is 
custom/modules/Opportunities/views/view.quickcreate.php

Unfortunately the constructor is not invoked.

Any help very appreciated.

```
<?php

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.quickcreate.php');

class OpportunitiesViewQuickcreate extends ViewQuickcreate {

    function OpportunitiesViewQuickcreate(){
        parent::ViewQuickcreate();
    }

    function preDisplay() {
        parent::preDisplay();
        $_REQUEST['custom_field_c'] = "a value for this field";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tens of trying, I've found solution.

The right way is to extend `SubpanelQuickCreate` in the file `custom/modules/Opportunities/views/view.subpanelquickcreate`

```
require_once('include/EditView/SubpanelQuickCreate.php');

class OpportunitiesSubpanelQuickcreate extends SubpanelQuickCreate {

    function OpportunitiesSubpanelQuickcreate() {
        $_REQUEST['custom_field_c'] = "a value for this field";
        parent::SubpanelQuickCreate("Opportunities");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going from memory, so I may be wrong, but try adding `$this->useForSubpanel = true;` in your constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately the constructor is not invoked.

Comment: It's very old PHP code, the OpportunitiesViewQuickcreate() function is basically the constructor.  If that doesn't work try setting it as a class property.  After that I'm out of ideas though.